# Difference in powershell result when invoked from C#

Tags: c#, powershell

Has anyone experienced any difference in the output when invoking a powershell script from C# compared to direct invocation from Powershell ISE?

**Scenario**

I am using a powershell script to get the data from a remote powershell. The way it is written in C# is

```
using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PSExecutionPolicyPreference", "RemoteSigned");

    // Execute the PS script which will internally invoke a remote PS script 
    // to return the data
    string scriptToExecute =  "content of script to execute";

    powerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptToExecute);
    results = powerShellInstance.Invoke();

    MessageBox.Show(results.Count.ToString());         
}
```

I am loading the "content of script dynamically" from a file.

When I execute this script from an application, it shows the results count as 45. If I run the same script (dynamic content of the script) from Powershell ISE, it returns 48 results and some of the values are also different.

Any help will be much appreciated.